# find the position of a sequence within a series of sequences

Tags: algorithm, sorting, position, series

I am having an array formed by n elements, each one with 2 possible values: x or o. The possible combinations are ordered so, if for example n=3, they would line up (horizontally) like this:

`o|x|o|o|x|x|o|x
 o|o|x|o|x|o|x|x
 o|o|o|x|o|x|x|x`

(first column: all o, last column: all x).
For n=4 the combinations will be ordered like:

`o|x|o|o|o|x|x|x|o|o|o|x|x|x|o|x
 o|o|x|o|o|x|o|o|x|x|o|x|x|o|x|x
 o|o|o|x|o|o|x|o|x|o|x|x|o|x|x|x
 o|o|o|o|x|o|o|x|o|x|x|o|x|x|x|x`

For n=5:

`o|x|o|o|o|o|x|x|x|x|o|o|o|o|o|x|o|x|x|x|x|x|o|o|o|o|x|x|x|x|o|x
 o|o|x|o|o|o|x|o|o|o|x|x|x|o|o|x|o|x|x|o|o|o|x|x|x|o|x|x|x|o|x|x
 o|o|o|x|o|o|o|x|o|o|x|o|o|x|x|x|o|o|o|x|x|o|x|x|o|x|x|x|o|x|x|x
 o|o|o|o|x|o|o|o|x|o|o|x|o|x|o|o|x|x|o|x|o|x|x|o|x|x|x|o|x|x|x|x
 o|o|o|o|o|x|o|o|o|x|o|o|x|o|x|o|x|o|x|o|x|x|o|x|x|x|o|x|x|x|x|x`

And so on.
I now want, given an array, to know where in the sequence it falls. I.e., if I have x|o|x|o, I would like to have a formula that tells me "it's on the 7th position". Of course, once I have as input the array, I know n, and so also the maximum length of the possible combinations (2^n).

I tried assigning a value to the "x"s so that the sequence of combinations is respected and each one has a unique value (the sum of the "x"s). For doing this, I assigned each row of the matrix an increasing value (1, 2, 2.5, 2.75, 2.875, 2.9375, etc). The point is that the values of the columns, calculated in that way, don't distribute proportionally among themselves, and even less among series with different n. The only thing that seems to work (with error increasing after n=5) is the ratio among a certain array and the one with all x (for the same n).

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: You say `n=3` and you show arrays with `8` elements. Please clarify.

Comment: the arrays are the vertical ones. I've put horizontally all the possible combinations (that for n=3 are 2^3=8).